# Simplification of summation and reverse search

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, recurrences, closed-form-expressions

Let $f(n)$ be an arbitrary function such that $f(n)\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Let $b(n)$ be an integer sequence such that
$$b(2^m(2n+1))=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m}f(m-k)b(2^kn), b(0)=1$$

Let $s(n,m)$ be an integer sequence such that
$$s(n,m)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{2^n-1}b(2^mk)$$

I conjecture that
$$s(n,m) = s(n+1,m-1) - \sum\limits_{k=0}^{m-1}f(m-k-1)s(n,k), s(0,m)=1$$

If we rewrite the formula, it will allow us to simplify the summation:
$$s(n,m)=s(n-1,m+1)+\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m}f(m-k)s(n-1,k), s(0,m)=1$$

This allows us to compute $f(n)$ if $s(n,0)$ is known:
$$f(n)=s(1,n)-1-\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}f(k)$$

Here is the PARI prog to verify these conjectures:

```
f(n)=n
s1(n)=my(v, v1); v=vector(2^n,i,0); v[1]=1; for(i=1,#v-1,my(A=valuation(i,2), B=i\2^(A+1)); v[i+1]=sum(j=0,A,f(A-j)*v[2^j*B+1])); v1=[1]; for(i=1,n,v1=concat(v1,sum(j=0,2^i-1,v[j+1]))); v1
s2(n)=my(v, v1); v=vector(n+1,i,1); v1=v; v2=vector(n+1,i,0); v2[1]=1; for(i=1,n,for(j=1,n-i+1,v1[j]=v[j+1]+sum(k=1,j,f(j-k)*v[k])); v=v1; v2[i+1]=v[1];); v2
test1(n)=s1(n)==s2(n)
f1(n)=my(A, B, v); A=vector(n+2,i,numbpart(i)); B=vector(n+2,i,if(i==1,A,vector(n-i+3,j,(j==1)))); v=vector(n+1,i,0); v[1]=A[2]-A[1]; for(i=2,n+1,for(j=2,i,B[j][i-j+2]=B[j-1][i-j+3]-sum(k=1,j-1,v[j-k]*B[k][i-j+2])); v[i]=B[i][2]-sum(j=1,i-1,v[j])-1); v
s3(n)=my(A=f1(n), v, v1); v=vector(n+1,i,1); v1=v; v2=vector(n+1,i,0); v2[1]=1; for(i=1,n,for(j=1,n-i+1,v1[j]=v[j+1]+sum(k=1,j,A[j-k+1]*v[k])); v=v1; v2[i+1]=v[1];); v2
test2(n)=my(A=s2(n), v); v=vector(n+1,i,A[i]==numbpart(i)); vecsum(v)==n+1
```

Here $f(n)=n$ gives $s(n,0)$ equals [A036765](https://oeis.org/A036765), i.e., number of ordered rooted trees with n non-root nodes and all outdegrees <= three. Also $s(n,0)$ equals [A000041](https://oeis.org/A000041), i.e., the number of partitions of n (the partition numbers) gives $f(n)$ equals [A176950](https://oeis.org/A176950) multiplied by $(-1)^n$. For other results, see [this topic](https://dxdy.ru/topic154347.html) on the **dxdy** scientific forum. It is very convenient to view the names and the first few terms of the sequence from the OEIS there. To do this, just hover the mouse over the link.

Is there a way to prove it?

Comment: The recurrence for $b$ needs a base case. I suspect you're assuming $b(0) = 1$.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, thank you for comment! Done.

Comment: Define $B_n(x)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}b(2^mn)x^m$ and $F(x)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}f(m)x^m$ also note $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{2\pi ikt/n}=[n\mid k]$ now use the latter identity for when $n$ is a power of $2$ and reduce your problem to a set of differential equations...